# JPEG files default to "bless" (Hex Editor), not to "eog" (Image Viewer)

Tags: nautilus, 10.04, file-association

I opened a JPEG file once with the HEX editor `bless`. Now Nautilus and GNOME in general have associated all JPEG files with `bless`. How do I get it to go back to `eog` (*Image Viewer*)?

I've tried enabling the *Remember this application for [...] files* checkbox in the *Open With Other Application...* menu but with no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug in your Ubuntu version. The [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/550004) contains following workaround:

> - right click the file in question
> - select PROPERTIES all the way down in the popup menu
> - go to "open with" tab
> - select an application that should be used by default
> - profit every time you double click

(This has to be done only once per file type.)

Answer (score 0):

While using **Ubuntu Tweak**, there is possibility to view all extensions associations.

Just click on the tab **File types manager**, and you'll see the associations and can change them.